# ExpressionEngine 2.7.3 How do I directly execute a query against the database?

Tags: mysql, query, admin.php

I navigate to
Tools | Data | SQL Manager

Select "Database Query Form"

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'flippityfloop'
```

I select "Enable MySQL Error Output" and hit [Submit]
The response contains the text "The query you submitted did not produce any results."

I go back to the "Database Query Form" and execute the same query with a valid column_name and I get no response. I get redirected to a root admin page with no route parameter in the QueryString.

Before I start inspecting Http Headers, can someone explain to me why this is happening? How do you get the following query to execute against the underlying database and display the results to the screen?

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'title'
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Profiler (Admin > System Administration > Output and Debugging) so you can see what the query actually being executed is. If you aren't getting results from the second query, I would suspect some server security module is likely interfering with the request, which would be revealed somewhat in the query log, as the query you ran either won't be there, or will have been modified. FWIW, the second query should work fine, and for a default install with no optional modules installed should return 14 tables (v2.9.2)